# nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "\#" in /etc/nginx/sites-enable d/default:20 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Tags: linux, wordpress, nginx

I'm trying to install wordpress via nginx on my raspberry pi by using some internet tutorials, but unfortunately I'm awful at Networking and I had a few block.

I'm using a new tutorial now and it seems that when I configured some files (the nginx conf probably) I encountered this error

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo service nginx start
Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "\#" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:20
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Can I get some help, please?

Comment: This is off-topic for SO; it belongs on [sf]

Comment: Server Fault is actually not the correct site either, as the question is not about **professional** server or infrastructure administration. [Super User](http://superuser.com/) is probably the correct destination.

Comment: And in any of these sites you shoud show what's in line 20 and around.

Comment: I downvote this from 1 to 0. No response.